# Extract a smart list from a queryset containing ManyToMany fields using Values in Django

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many

I basically have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField()
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(AnotherModel)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    lang = models.CharField()
```

and I would like to get a list of dicts like this (of course possibly filtering, but that works fine):

```
[{
    'uid': uid,
    'm2m': [m2m.name, m2m.name, ...]
}]
```

If I do:

```
MyModel.objects.select_related('m2m').filter().values('uid', 'm2m__name')
```

I get the following:

```
[{
    'uid': name_1,
    'm2m__name': m2m_1.name
},{
    'uid': name_1,
    'm2m__name': m2m_2.name
}]
```

where I have **two problems**:

1. I get a separate list item *per each* m2m! I only would like one per UID, with m2m names in a list
2. I get "m2m__name" where I would like only "name" or maybe "m2m"

(if I don't explicitly ask `m2m__name` and only use `m2m` I do not get **unicode** but the ID)

Is there a way to solve these problems straight into the queryset without going through a python loop? What's the most efficient way?

**EDIT**

...maybe using .raw() or .extra() and some self-baked SQL could at least solve question 2. ?

- [.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields)
- [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: Come on! I do not want to accept my own answer!!! :) There MUST be a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds weird to me that nobody has any interest into this question, but I ended up looping over the results to build my own desired list:

```
my_list = {}
for item in items:
    _uid = item['uid']
    _name = item['m2m__name']
    list_item = my_list.get(, {'uid': _uid, 'name': set([_name])})
    list_item['name'].add(_name)
```

this will result into something like:

```
my_list = { 'uid': {
    'uid': uid,
    'm2m': [m2m.name, m2m.name, ...]
}}
```

which items are exactly what required in the question.

I would have liked to be able to solve at least one of the issues at QuerySet level though...

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact question myself and had to piece multiple pieces of information together to get my answer. So for others here's what I found. This only works if you are using **Postgres >= 9.4** and **Django >= 9.0**.

You can do the following:

```
MyModel.objects.filter( ... ).values('uid', names=ArrayAgg('m2m__name'))
```

Will yield the following:

```
<MyModelQuerySet [{'uid': 'id_1', 'names': ['name_1', 'name_2', ...]}]>
```